# Contao > 4.3 sending emails with sendmail throw error on some providers

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, contao

Older Versions of Contao (till 4.3) working like expected with sending emails via sendmail.
After upgrade to Contao 4.9 I got some errors at Providers like 1u1 / ionos or mittwald.

The error in the logs sound like:

> "Expected response code 220 but got an empty response"

Sending Mails from CLI of the Server (means if logged in via SSH) working like expected:sendmail test" |

> /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -v -f sender@domain.com reciepient@otherOne.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add this to **config/config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
  default_mailer: default
  mailers:
    default:
      url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
      transport: sendmail
      command: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'
```

After that, clear the Contao-Cache (e.g. via contao-manager.phar) and give it a try.

The reason for that issue is, that by default the swiftMailer use `sendmail -bs` as command, which means that sendmail run as `standalone` Service.
Depending at the way your provider configure it's sendmail, this will be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you update `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` to version **3.5.0**, then the default value used for the `sendmail` command will be read from the PHP configuration. See https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/pull/302

So provided the PHP configuration of your hosting environment contains the correct command in `sendmail_path`, sending emails should work without any changes.

Comment: The Provider ionos.de makes trouble with it, all the time. Don't see how to change anything there for the default-php-config.